# Use stored Cookie in persistentcookiejar or some other container for okhttp requests in android

Tags: android, redirect, cookies, session-cookies, okhttp

**This question basically wants to know how to use stored cookies for subsequent request.** The long text below is just for example. *Basic question is how to use the same cookie for all requests on a particular website.*

Basically I am trying to reach the login page of a website within the android app. The website works the following way.

There are 3 urls to consider.

1 -> "http://www.example.com/timeoutPage"

2 -> "http://www.example.com/mainPage"

3 -> "http://www.example.com/loginPage"

**The two main points to consider are**

(1) If we directly go to the 3rd url (loginPage), it redirects to the 1st url(timeoutPage). The timeoutPage has a button to go to the mainPage.

(2) If we go to the 2nd url (mainPage), it gives us a cookie. Now, after getting the cookie, when we visit the 3rd url (loginPage),  we are able to access it. The loginPage has a captcha so it's essential to visit it(loginPage) in order to login.

**Without the cookie, which is given at visiting 2nd url(mainPage), we cannot directly access 3rd url(loginPage).**

so what i am doing is to make a ClearableCookieJar and *attach* it to OkHttpClient.

```
OkHttpClient client;
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar;
```

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this));
```

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .build();
```

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://www.example.com/mainPage")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textView.setText("Failed to get response");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Everthing is fine till here as i am able to print the html of mainPage in my textview.
Problem starts here when i make another request for the loginPage.

```
request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://www.example.com/loginPage")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textView.setText("Failed to get response");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse2 = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(myResponse2);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Here i again make  a request to the loginPage but i reach the timeoutPage. How should i make the request for the loginPage url so that my request sends the cookie which i stored in the cookieJar while making a request to mainPage. One way i thought of was

```
request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://www.example.com/loginPage")
                .addHeader("Cookie", cookieStringGivenAtMainPage)
                .build();
```

But i don't know how to access that cookieStringGivenAtMainPage. How should i reach that loginPage?

*I print the html of the response to see if i reached the correct page.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer you want to know is the singleton pattern.
Please refer to below sample code. I got it from kakao developer site about 3 years ago.

```
    public class NetworkManager {

    private static NetworkManager instance;

    private OkHttpClient client;

    /**
     * By using Singleton Pattern we can share cookie, client values.
     **/

    private NetworkManager() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        Context context = GlobalApplication.getGlobalApplicationContext();

        ClearableCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));
        builder.cookieJar(cookieJar);

        builder.followRedirects(true);
        builder.addInterceptor(new RedirectInterceptor());

        File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "network");

        if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
            cacheDir.mkdir();
        }

        Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        builder.cache(cache);

        builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        client = builder.build();
    }

    public static NetworkManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NetworkManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public OkHttpClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

In addition below is sample usage.

```
OkHttpClient client = NetworkManager.getInstance().getClient();

RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("userId", getTargetUserId())
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("www.test.com/insert.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
```